# In aspx with mvc 4, how to modify layout pages slightly on opening of a new page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery

When an htmlActionLink is clicked, a new page (say About) is opened with layout and the main body is rendered from the corresponding view. I want to change the style of the about link to show that this link is active. I tried a lot using jquery. It changes momentarily, but it comes back to its original style. I have not tried it through controller. I've used jquery in the layout.cshtml and about.cshtml page.

Comment: You will get better answers if you include some code showing what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

Look in to MvcSiteMap. You can use the MVC helpers to create a navigation menu that changes as you visit pages.  Also,  keeping it server side over using jQuery is going to be the best bet.